# Explanation Required for this Particular For Loop

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain this piece of code for me, I am a beginner and I couldn't understand the `For` Loop here, This code can arrange the numbers from smallest to largest.

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int [] sayilarr ={a,b,c,d};
Array.Sort(sayilarr);
string ss = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ss += sayilarr[i];

}
Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

Comment: numbers are arranged with `Array.Sort(sayilarr);` Statement, not with `for` loop.

Comment: Just try and run the code. Step through it in debug mode when you still not get it. Don't post this kind of questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code takes 4 inputs from the Console, converts them to Int and saves them into 4 variables

```
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then you declare an array, which will contain the four ints from the variables

```
    int [] sayilarr ={a,b,c,d};
```

Now this array is sorted, no magic loop trick ...

```
    Array.Sort(sayilarr);
```

Here a string variable is declared, initially being an empty string

```
    string ss = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
```

in each of the four loops the content of the array on index "i" is concatenated

```
        ss += sayilarr[i];
    }
```

Finally, the string is shown to you

```
  Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

Hope this is clear now :-)